# How is Hangfire able to be independent from ASP.net?

Tags: hangfire

```
No Windows Service, no Windows Scheduler, no separate applications required.
```

Without these tools how is Hangfire able to run background tasks without being tied to ASP.net?

Comment: It can't - it needs a process to run in. This is either IIS or Windows Service.

Comment: have you even read the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hangfire has no references to `System.Web` or other assemblies related to ASP.NET. All the Hangfire features including the dashboard (web UI) can be used in any application type like console application or Windows service. This is why it is independent of ASP.NET.

Hangfire handles all the [risks of running background jobs](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/) inside ASP.NET applications, including application restarts (jobs are persisted) and unexpected process terminations (retry logic is used). So you can process background jobs without using Windows Services or separate applications.

Comment: Great. But how does it host background jobs?

Comment: @IanWarburton - have you even read the docs? Background jobs are queued to some persistent storage and then executed within the context of a process. This process is usually IIS, but hangfire can also be configured to run standalone in a windows service.

Comment: Its not clear to me. Please direct me to where it explains that background jobs are hosted within IIS.

Comment: @IanWarburton where else are they going to be hosted? In ASP.NET, IIS provides the .net runtime environment as a w3wp worker process. This is the only place available to execute code inside.

Comment: That's the point of the question. I don't know where they'd be hosted.

Comment: How can you not know? If you call `app.UseHangfireServer()` or `using (new BackgroundJobServer)` (equivalent for this question) in ASP.NET app that will be hosted in IIS, background jobs will be processed in IIS. If in a console app, then in a console app, the same with Windows service.

Comment: Because IIS processes web pages. I don't understand how it can run a long running process which is not returning a web page.

Comment: @IanWarburton, every ASP.NET application is able to spawn background threads with any processing logic. Hangfire uses this feature to process background job, and ensures that background processing will be continued even in case of a process termination.

Comment: I've always read that doing that from ASP.net is fraught with problems. Seems that frameworks such as Hangfire are able to do it properly.